# Adding qmake to path

Tags: path, qmake, pkg-config

I'm trying to set up a Qt dev environment on my machine with Windows 8.1.

I'm trying to add qmake to my path. On my machine, `qmake.exe` is in `C:/Qt/Qt5.3.2/5.3/mingw482_32/bin/`. I've added this to my path via System Properties, but I fear that I might be doing this incorrectly based on how finicky Windows is with the Path.

I've got something to like this:

```
...path that I know is correct...;\C:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\5.3\mingw482_32\bin\;...rest of the path...
```

However, when I issue qmake within bash, I'm still told that qmake is not found. I'm having a similar issue with pkg-config, but I think solving one will solve the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slash in front of `C:\\...` was the troublemaker.